# In Workflow how to get sub string from multiline text field?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

How to get sub string in 2010 workflow from multi line text fields.
String like

John Al

Andre Ale

I want to get this string in my local variable like **"John Al;Andre Ale"**